# How to call completionHandler for performFetchWithCompletionHandler in Swift

Tags: swift, uiapplication

how can I call the completion Handler for the background fetch in Swift. I do the following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Do something

    completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData) // This does not work :(

    return

}
```

Can you please help me? Thanks,

Tobi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enum case is `UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData`, so the correct way is:

```
completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
```

or even:

```
completionHandler (.NoData)
```

because the type can be inferred from the closure signature

Hint: when unsure about a function signature, or enum cases, etc., in Xcode write the type, in this case `UIBackgroundFetchResult`, and then cmd+click it to go to the definition, or option+click to popup its declaration. That usually helps a lot.

Comment: Oh man in the Documentation it looked like the cases were used without the point. Thank you!