# Receiving remote notifications in ios app in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

There are two methods:

1) didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo

2) didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo fetchCompletionHandler

What is the difference between these 2 methods and when are they called?
Also, How do i determine if app is active or not when the notification arrives?
Lastly, what is the completionhandler that is passed in the second function? And **how do i use the completion handler to handle the notification**?

Answer (score 1):

The fetch completion handler can be used if you are using any background processing. For example, if the push comes in and the app is in the background, you can use background fetch to make a request for you. An example of this may be if a message comes through whilst the app is in the background, you could use background fetch to make a server request to pull data down for that push notification so that when the user opens the app the data is already there. Essentially it is just a completion handler if there is any functionality run on the reception of a push notification whilst the app is in the background. From my example above, the completion handler would inform you that the request has been completed.

References you may find helpful are:

[iOS Background Fetch and completion block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002203/ios-background-fetch-and-completion-block)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

This final link explains how to call it :

[How to call completionHandler for performFetchWithCompletionHandler in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873270/how-to-call-completionhandler-for-performfetchwithcompletionhandler-in-swift)